# Chartjs in real time

Tags: time, chart.js

I am unable to view my data in real time.
Indeed, according to the script that I am offering you, the chart is fully displayed each time and includes all the data.
I can't display the new data after the "old" ones.
Thank you very much.

```
var ' . $var1 . ' = [];
        var ' . $var2 . ' = [];
        var data = {
            labels: '.$var1.',
            datasets: [{
                label: "data",
                data: '.$var2.',
                backgroundColor: "#0156AC",
                pointStyle: "circle",
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointHoverRadius: 10
            }]
        };
        
        var config = {
            type: "line",
            data: data
        };
        
        var myChart = new Chart (
            document.getElementById("myChart"),
            config
        );
                    
        var getData = function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "' . $url . '",
                success: function(data) {
                    for(var i in data) {
                        if (' . $var1 . '.length >= 20) {
                            ' . $var1 . '.shift();
                            ' . $var2 . '.shift();
                        }
                        ' . $var1 . '.push("" + data[i].' . $var1 . ');
                            ' . $var2 . '.push(data[i].' . $var2 . ');
                    }   
                }
            }); 
            myChart.update();
        }
                    
            setTimeout(getData, 1000);
            setInterval(getData, 2000);
```

Comment: Supposing that the weird `' . $var1 . '` and  `' . $var12. '` stuff (what's that anyway? try to make things easier for us, use plain javascript) are preprocessed to some real javascript variable names, this appears to be the right pattern to update the chart with "live" data. What actually happens really depends on the `data` returned by the ajax call - it might be an empty array, or it may be the same data repeated -- if it's always `success`, and always returns something different, and you have no errors in console, then you should see some change every 2 seconds.